# How to export selections made in tkinter Combobox to Excel or text File?

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

I'm working on a program that will be used for internally ordering parts between stores. Currently I have the GUI working perfectly, and the code has no errors.

[image: GUI]

I want to have a button at the bottom of the GUI that will say send, which will read the selections made, and then export those into a file that can be read by the logistics department. I have scoured the internet but cant seem to find such thing for python.

I would prefer it to export the selections into a excel spreadsheet, but text file will do too, if it can be coded so that it would be easy to read.

As I received a bad comment on the last post, I'll post code for the two kinds of selection boxes, i have. The code pasted into a .py file will open a similar GUI.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry("400x400")

def openiPhone5():
    iPhone5 = Toplevel(master)
    iPhone5.geometry("800x800")
    Label(iPhone5,
          text="iPhone 5").grid()
    #Variabel til iPhone 5 Farver
    iPhone5Colors =('Sort', 'Hvid')

    #PARTS###

    #OrginalSkærm
    OGscreen = Combobox(iPhone5)
    OGscreenColor = Combobox(iPhone5)
    OGscreen['values'] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "Text")
    OGscreenColor['values'] = iPhone5Colors
    OGscreen.current(0)  # set the selected item
    OGscreenColor.grid(column=3, row=7)
        #CUSTOM
    CustomAmount = Combobox(iPhone5)
    CustomTEXT = Combobox(iPhone5)
    CustomTEXT['text'] = (1, "Text")
    CustomAmount['values'] = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "Text")
    CustomAmount.current(0)  # set the selected item
    CustomAmount.grid(column=3, row=18)
    CustomTEXT.grid(column=3, row=17)
    Custom_lbl = Label(iPhone5,
                       text="Custom")
    Custom_lbl.grid(column=1, row=17)

def openNewWindow1():
    # Toplevel object which will
    # be treated as a new window
    newWindow1 = Toplevel(master)

    # sets the title of the
    # Toplevel widget
    newWindow1.title("Apple")

    # sets the geometry of toplevel
    newWindow1.geometry("800x800")

    # A Label widget to show in toplevel
    Label(newWindow1,
          text="iPhones").grid()
    btn = Button(newWindow1,
                 text="iPhone 5",
                 command=openiPhone5)
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the user chosen value out of the `Combobox`? If so, the question doesn't really need the `tkinter` tag.

Comment: @TheLizzard no i dont know that, sadly. Im new on this site, so i dont know which tags to use, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry. Just for the future: tags are used to ask certain people for help. For example I answer questions tagged with `tkinter` but I don't really know how excel works. If you use the correct tags for the question, you are more likely to get a better answer from someone who has knowledge in that field.

Comment: You've explained what you're creating, but you haven't asked a question. What part of the problem are you struggling with?

Comment: @BryanOakley "I want to have a button at the bottom of the GUI that will say send, which will read the selections made, and then export those into a file that can be read by the logistics department. I have scoured the internet but cant seem to find such thing for python."

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you, do you possibly know how to export the user chosen value to a txt file then?

Comment: @BryanOakley I need help getting the data out of the widget, i havent asked for anyone to write code for me, i feel like you are just after me for some reason, this is the 2nd time you commented my posts, with all negativeness. If you can post the documention i would appreciate it, as i can not find anything coming anywhere close. I do not know how to get the data out of the combobox, or how to write this data to a external file. If you can help me with this, or send me some documentation covering this, thank you. If not, have a nice day Bryan.

Comment: _" i havent asked for anyone to write code for me, i feel like you are just after me for some reason,"_ - I'm not after you, it's just that your question is just a set of requirements. You haven't shown any effort in trying to solve this problem yourself. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432). I'm just trying to get you to be more specific about what type of help you need since it's not at all evident from the question itself.

Comment: You can store the references of those `Combobox` in a list, then go through the list and use `<Combobox>.get()` to get the selected items when you want to export them to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to start by associating a variable with each combobox. You can then store those variables in a list or dictionary. To get the data out it's just a matter of iterating over the list or dictionary and calling `get` on each variable.

Here's an example of a very simplistic example that creates 10 comboboxes with associated variables:

```
combo_vars = []
for i in range(10):
    var = tk.StringVar(root, value=0)
    combo_vars.append(var)
    label = tk.Label(form, text=f"Value {i+1}:")
    combo = ttk.Combobox(form, textvariable=var, width=20, values=list(range(5)))

    label.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="e")
    combo.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky="w")
```

For example, assuming you have a variable named `combo_vars` that contains instances of `StringVar` such as in the previous example, you can get all of the values and print them out in a simple loop. There's a more concise way of doing this using list comprehensions, but I'm using the more verbose method to make it easier to understand.

```
values = []
for var in combo_vars:
    value = var.get()
    values.append(value)
```

With that, `values` has a list of the values. You can then do whatever you want with that list: convert them to a comma-separated list, write them to a database, convert them to json, save them to an excel file, or whatever it is you need to do.

For example, to write a comma-separated list to a file you can use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) like so:

```
import csv
...
with open("data.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, values)
    writer.writerow(values)
```